# How to append a value with button's ID in runtime?

Tags: javascript

I am using below javaScript code to create table in runtime. And i somewhat assumed to append a value into the ID of the button. Will it work. I am confused because of double quotes.

```
function createTable(){
EmployeeManagement.getList(function(data){
var employee = data;

var x = "<table border= 1 >";
    x+="<thead> " + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Check" + "</td><td>" + "ID" + "</td><td>" + "Name" + "</td><td>" + "Age" + "</td><td>" + "Dept" + "</td><td>" + "Option" + "</td></tr></thead>";
    for(i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        var id = data[i].id;
    x+= "<tr>";
    x+= "<td>" + "<input type=checkbox name=Employee value='emp'+id />"
    x+= "<td>" + data[i].id + "</td><td>" + data[i].name + "</td>";
    x+= "<td>" + data[i].age + "</td><td>" + data[i].dept + "</td>";
    x+= "<td>" + "<input id='edit'+id type='button' value='Edit' onclick=edit(this.id) />" + "</td>"; 
    x+= "</tr>";
    }
    x+= "</table>";
    $('#tableHolder').html(x);
});
   }
```

**here, i want to append the id value, to the ID value id BUTTON.
I already coded for it. Will it work or how to make it work.
I can use jquery means, how???
Any suggestions would be appreciative...
Thanks**

Comment: 1) "Will it work?" → Did you try it? What was the result? 2) Why do you use `"<thead> " + "<tr>" + "<td>" +` *etc.*? One string is enough 3) What does `EmployeeManagement.getList` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't work. Just do it the same as with the other strings, use string concatenation:

```
"<input id='edit" + id + "' type='button' value='Edit' onclick=edit(this.id) />" 
//              --^  --^
```

Currently, you are generating invalid HTML. But you could have tried yourself to find this out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation...  Also your cells in subsequent rows should match the number of cells in your head row.

```
function createTable(){
EmployeeManagement.getList(function(data){
var employee = data;

var x = "<table border= 1 >";
    x+="<thead> " + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Check" + "</td><td>" + "Name" + "</td><td>" + "Dept" + "</td><td>" + "Option" + "</td></tr></thead>";
    for(i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        var id = data[i].id;
    x+= "<tr>";
    x+= "<td>" + "<input type=checkbox name=Employee value='emp"+id+"' /> </td>";
    x+= "<td>" + data[i].id + "</td><td>" + data[i].name + "</td>";
    x+= "<td>" + data[i].age + "</td><td>" + data[i].dept + "</td>";
    x+= "<td>" + "<input id='edit"+id+"' type='button' value='Edit' onclick=edit(this.id) />" + "</td>"; 
    x+= "</tr>";
    }
    x+= "</table>";
    $('#tableHolder').html(x);
});
   }
```

Comment: hey what is it... I cant understand.

Comment: I assume this is what you're asking...  You want the value of the Employee field to be emp##  where ## is the employee id?

Comment: Also look at the `edit` ID. And if you're posting the whole function, correct it a bit more, please (string concatenation, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work. Assuming the id is FOO, the html to generate is:

```
<input id='editFOO' type='button' ...
```

which can be done by splitting it up into three parts like so:

```
"<input id='edit" + id + "' type='button' ..."
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript vars inside a double quoted string are not interpreted. So you have to put the vars outside of the string. Replace e.g. this:

```
"<input type=checkbox name=Employee value='emp'+id />"
```

with this:

```
"<input type=checkbox name=Employee value='emp" + id "' />"
```